# Return a List<MyObject> based on very similar data

Tags: c#

I am rewriting an old VB.NET app in C#. I will not subject you to the old VB.NET code that I am writing (the original method that I have already refactored was over 700 lines long).

The following is what we call On Demand Reports. There is a stored procedure that these objects fill in for us. I don't have a 100% understanding of why most of what I am doing is just static string text but it is.

What I want to do is to find a better way to represent the `List<MyObject>` (see the embedded comments).

```
 private IEnumerable<MyObject> GetOnDemandInputsBy(int key)
        {
            var inputs = new List<MyObject>();
            //This is actually called 13 times with different parameter variables (the parameter called parameter) and a different static dictionary 
            inputs.Add(AssembleMyObject(key, "@BeginTime", MyObjectPropertyConstants.BeginTime()));
            inputs.Add(AssembleMyObject(key, "@EndTime", MyObjectPropertyConstants.EndTime()));

            return inputs;
        }

        //This method is fine with me. It is just here for context
        private static IEnumerable<MyObjectProperty> AssembleMyObjectProperty(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {

            return dictionary.Select(item => new MyObjectProperty {PropertyName = item.Key, PropertyValue = item.Value});
        }

        //I feel like I am passing to many things into this method and its doing to much
        private MyObject AssembleMyObject(int key, string parameter, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            //this is set to 0 in the constructor, I am not sure why the original developers chose 10 for every new object
            _displayOrder += 10;
            var MyObject = new MyObject
            {
                DisplayOrder = _displayOrder,
                ParameterName = parameter,
                QueryKey = key,
            };
            MyObject.MyObjectProperties.AddRange(AssembleMyObjectProperty(dictionary));
            return MyObject;
        }

    //This seems like a bad idea as well but all the data is static and I created a separate dictionary for each of the parameter types     
    public class MyObjectPropertyConstants
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> BeginTime()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"stuff", "@BeginTime"},
                {"VISIBLE", "TRUE"},
                {"CAPTION", "*beginTime"},
                {"DISPLAYTYPE", "DATEPICKER"},
                {"DATATYPE", "DATE"},
            };
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> EndTime()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Name", "@EndTime"},
                {"VISIBLE", "TRUE"},
                {"CAPTION", "*EndTime"},
                {"DISPLAYTYPE", "DATEPICKER"},
                {"DATATYPE", "DATE"},
            };
        }
   }
```

As previously states this is the refactored version so far. The original code to do the above chunk is 180 lines. The method that I am rewriting is over 700 lines long.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is `parameter` guaranteed to be `'@' + method name`?

Comment: @svick Yes it can always be. It doesn't matter what I name the methods

Comment: It seems to me that you're mixing a lot of "data" with the code. Maybe loading the key value pair data from files? Also, more importantly, I have no context as to what the code actually does.

Comment: This code is called from a web app. We are getting all of the "On-Demand" reports from the key passed down from the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var inputs = new List<MyObject>();
inputs.Add(AssembleMyObject(key, "@BeginTime", MyObjectPropertyConstants.BeginTime()));
inputs.Add(AssembleMyObject(key, "@EndTime", MyObjectPropertyConstants.EndTime()));

return inputs;
```

You could rewrite this to make it more DRY using LINQ into:

```
return new Func<Dictionary<string, string>>[]
{
    MyObjectPropertyConstants.BeginTime,
    MyObjectPropertyConstants.EndTime
}.Select(f => AssembleMyObject(key, "@" + f.Name, f()).ToList();
```

---

```
var MyObject
```

Local variables are usually named in camelCase, e.g. `myObject`.

---

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> BeginTime()
```

Method should be named using verbs, this looks more like a property. Thought making this into a property would make the above LINQ rewrite more difficult.

---

```
new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"stuff", "@BeginTime"},
    {"VISIBLE", "TRUE"},
    {"CAPTION", "*beginTime"},
    {"DISPLAYTYPE", "DATEPICKER"},
    {"DATATYPE", "DATE"},
};
```

Does order matter here? If it does, you shouldn't use `Dictionary`, since it doesn't guarantee ordering.

Comment: I missed the MyObject variable when I sanitized my code. Order doesn't matter.